# Date picker not displaying in primefaces 4.0 due to validation of facesContext

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsf, primefaces

Hi I am having a technical issue with my web application (Primefaces 4.0, Java/Spring/Hibernate), I have validation on all my date such that the user cannot select a date in the future. When my validation is displayed on the form, it blocks all datepicker from being displayed.

Below is the error in firebug:

Error: TypeError: this.jqEl.datepicker is not a function
src="#{request.contextPath}/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces"> - line 6

Page source before validation is being displayed:

```
            <head>


    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    @import url("/BUS/resources/dojo/resources/dojo.css");
    @import url("/BUS/resources/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css");
    </style>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/BUS/resources/dojo/dojo.js" djconfig="parseOnLoad: true" ></script>

         <script type="text/javascript" src="/BUS/resources/spring/Spring.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/BUS/resources/spring/Spring-Dojo.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">dojo.require("dojo.parser");</script>

    <link href="/BUS/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 



    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/BUS/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces-aristo" />
```

```
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Sat,  01 Dec 2001 00:00:00 GMT" />


    <script type="text/javascript" src="/BUS/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces"></script>



    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/BUS/css/jsfdefault.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/BUS/js/export.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/BUS/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces" />
    <style type="text/css">
```

Page source after validation is being displayed:

```
 <head>

    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        @import url("/BUS/resources/dojo/resources/dojo.css");
        @import url("/BUS/resources/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css");
    </style>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/BUS/resources/dojo/dojo.js" djconfig="parseOnLoad: true" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/BUS/resources/spring/Spring.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/BUS/resources/spring/Spring-Dojo.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">dojo.require("dojo.parser");</script>

    <link href="/BUS/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 


    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/BUS/images/favicon.gif" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/BUS/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces-aristo" />


    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Sat,  01 Dec 2001 00:00:00 GMT" />


    <script type="text/javascript" src="/BUS/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces"></script>



    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/BUS/css/jsfdefault.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/BUS/themes/bluesky/skin.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/BUS/js/export.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="/BUS/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=4.0"></script>

           <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/BUS/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces" />
    <style type="text/css">
```

I can see it adds a script for jquery.js in the page source after the validation. I think it creates a conflict and this is why my datepicker is not working. Can someone help on this ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see where jquery.js is being added to the page, and that shouldn't be a problem anyway.  I noticed that it looks like EL expressions are not being rendered properly on your page.  The part in your error where you see #{request.contextPath} should be resolved to the applications context path in the rendered html but this does not seem to be occurring.  That is strange.

Comment: I just modified the above code. the one after validation it import jquery.js( just after export.js).  #{request.contextPath} I use this to import css file and it works.

Comment: Manage to solve the problem. I had to remove this <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" /> and add these two scripts   <script type="text/javascript" src="#{BUS/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=4.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="#BUS/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery-plugins.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=4.0"></script>

Now am having another issue,normally when my validation is displayed, it reloads the page.But this does not keep track of the records in tabview. Anyone can help on this?

Comment: Because it is a different issue entirely I suggest opening a new question.

Comment: Ok I did it here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22953508/ptabview-is-not-keeping-track-of-data-when-page-is-reloaded-in-primefaces-4-0
Glad if u can help. Thanks :)