# <p:tabview> is not keeping track of data when page is reloaded in PrimeFaces 4.0

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces

Hi I have some validation on my form (Java web application), and when the validation is displayed, it should reload the page. When it does this, I lose all the data input in the dropdown list in first tab.(Data in text boxes are retained)

Below is how I define my tabview :

```
<p:tabView id="tabView" dynamic="true">
```

Anyone can help on this? Thanks in Advance

I am using PrimeFaces 4.0, spring, hibernate.

```
   <h:form prependId="false">
     <p:panel>
          <h:panelGrid id="detail" columns="2" styleClass="grid"columnClasses="label,value">


              <p:tabView id="tabView" dynamic="true" >


                 <p:tab id="tab1" title="bUS Details">

                  <h:outputTextvalue="#{ebusmsgs['ebus.bustitle.title']}:" />

                  <h:inputText id="ebus_bustitle" value="#{BusComponent.bus.empMinDiv}" />
                 </p:tab>

                 <p:tab id="tab2" title="Mechanic Details">
                     <h:outputTextvalue="#{ebusmsgs['ebus.mechanictitle.title']}:" />

                     <h:inputText id="ebus_mechanictitle" value="#{BusComponent.bus.empMinDiv}" />
                 </p:tab>
              </p:tabView>
          </h:panelGrid>
     </p:panel>
   </h:form>
```

Comment: Can I see the code of your form and your managed bean?

Comment: Please see code above. I dont have a manage bean. I use interface